# Can data scaling improve Deep RL Learning? If yes, Why?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I saw a DRL application in which the input is scaled between -1 and 1 first before training, why it is needed? How does it help with the training?

Answer (score 1):

Normalizing/Standardizing data it's a widely known technique in ML/DL in order to have a better convergence of algorithms such as neural network, which are widely used in DRL